# Does a Sri Lankan need transit visas for Korea and Malaysia?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, south-korea, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan passport holder and I am living in in the Northern Mariana Islands, a US territory, on a CW2 visa. I'm planning to travel to Sri Lanka by the end of the month and have to transit in Korea and Malaysia.

Do I need any transit visas? I have no more than 5 hours waiting time for my next flights. I am flying via T'way Airlines to Korea and Air Asia Airlines to Malaysia and on to Colombo.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues here. The airlines you choose are point to point airlines so you must clear immigration to check-in again in Korea.

Each airport in Korea is subject to different transit rules.

Timatic says: Korea (Rep.) (KR)

Visa Exemptions:

- Nationals of any country with a visa issued by Australia,

  Austria, Belgium, Canada, Cyprus, Czech Rep., Denmark,
  Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland,
  Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania,
  Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland,
  Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden,
  Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom if in transit through
  Korea (Rep.) must: 
  -hold confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within

  30 days; when
  -arriving from the country that issued the visa (a visa that
  expired on departure from that country is accepted) and
  departing to a third country.

That would indicate that if you hold a valid USA visa you can transit Korea, even with a point to point ticket.

For Malaysia, assuming you are just transiting an not stopping over for a few days and stay on Air Asia then you will be fine.

Visa required, except for Holders of a valid visa issued by
Australia, China (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea
(Rep.), New Zealand or USA to nationals of Sri Lanka residing

in country of nationality holding confirmed onward tickets for

a max. transit For details, click here time of 120 hours, arriving at
and departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) on Malaysia Airlines

(MH) or Air Asia (AK). When transit time is longer than 8 hours it is permitted to leave the transit area if:

Transit between Main Terminal and KLIA2 is
   also permitted. When leaving the airport transit area,
   passports must be valid for at least 6 months from date of
   arrival.

Comment: The CW visa seems to be an odd special case: it's issued by the United States government, but doesn't actually permit the holder to enter the 50 US states.  But if the wording really is "issued by" then I suppose it works.